# API Key vs Client Identifier

Tags: api, vimeo, vimeo-api

everyone!

I'm hoping this is a simple question, but I'm trying to use one of the great Vimeo API Libraries created by users, but I'm really confused by the constant references to an API Key. When I setup my application in Vimeo, it game me a Client Identifier, Client Secret, Request Token URL, Authorize URL and Access Token URL.

Did I skip a step? Because I've never seen anything label API Key or API Secret.

If someone could please point me in the proper direction, I'd be greatly appreciative.

Thanks!

-Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Key and Client ID are usually the same thing.
Same with API Secret and Client Secret.

You are the client, and you use your ID and secret with the Vimeo API.

The Request Token URL, Authorize URL and Access Token URL are all parts of the authentication process that should already be hard coded into the API library.

Comment: Thanks, Dashron. I just wanted to double check, so I appreciate the help. I get skeptic when namings don't line up. :)